# Restart memory card game on completion

Tags: android

Hey guys I'm a beginner at Android Development so any help would be much appreciated!

**The problem**

I'm making a card game which at the end of it has a card shaking animation done endlessly. The thing I want to add is whenever the user taps on anything on the screen, I want to make the game start all over again

**Details**

Note that I have a linear layout as a background and several buttons(these are the cards) aligned on the linear layout (if needed I can provide the code and the xml file)

**My kind of solution**

What I thought could work was an "invisible" dialog box which could on click end the current game activity and start the intent of the same activity..is that right and if so how can I make an invisible dialog box (not transparent)?

If you need anything don't hesitate to ask I'll provide it as soon as I can!

**Update**

Here's the part of my code where I want to do what I've said above

```
if (correctCounter>2){


        for(int ct=0;ct<memoCards.length;ct++){
            memoCards[ct].setClickable(false);
        }




        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int temp = (int) (Math.random() * 5);
                        Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.shake);
                        memoCards[temp].startAnimation(shake);
                    }
                });



            }
        },0,1000);



}
```

what I want is when a touch event is being made on screen I want the game to start again

Comment: Please give some code a try and come back if something is not working, my suggestion would be to implement an onfininshed on your animation and then restart your activity etc

Comment: thanks for the answer dave but I think I want a different thing..I tried to rephrase so if you want to you can have a second look on my updated question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your issue, what you need is to implement OnClickListener for your activity, i.e.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener{

    ImageView b1;
    TextView b2;
    int correctCounter=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout ln2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll1);
        ln2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        b2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                correctCounter++;
                if (correctCounter>20) {
                    View parent = (View) v.getParent();
                    parent.performClick();
                }
            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                correctCounter++;
                if (correctCounter>20) {
                    View parent = (View) v.getParent();
                    parent.performClick();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            if (correctCounter>20) {
                /*Restart Activity*/
            }
    }
}
```

The listener will respect your child components' click events and only trigger if you click on free space.

EDIT: I'm adding a layout xml for better understanding of the logic

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ll1">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer :)...yeah I thought about that but I was wondering if there was a way to create something like an invisible layout in front of all the elements I have so that I can use the onClickListener you suggested?

Comment: If you create an invisible layout in front of your elements then you will have to find a way for your layout to know whether your click is on itself or the elements below. With my suggestion, which is to implement OnClickListener on the parent layout, that is already implemented. Do you have any particular reason for having that extra layout other than for the onClick?

Comment: I want to add this extra layout so that if the user clicks on the cards or the background it doesn't matter and the game starts again..if I add the onClickListener on the background layout then the game will start only if the user touches the background, which is fine when the cards are not much(for example 6), but is not fine when the cards are a lot(for example 20) and they pretty much cover the 90% of the background, you get what I'm saying right ?

Comment: I've edited my solution based on your needs. Note that I insist on avoiding the extra layout, because there is much overhead that you should avoid. The key part in code is "View parent = (View) v.getParent(); parent.performClick();" which is the way for the child components to communicate and trigger their parent's onClick.